# Accessing one file from another in a different directory

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I hope this all makes sense however I can't find a way to word it in order to find my answer anywhere so I thought I would try this...

okay so imagine a folder in this folder is my website homepage also in this folder is 2 different folders one is called scripts the other is called css. now my website can link up to both of these using the following...

> /scripts/myjsfile.js
>   /css/mycssfile.css

However in my js file I make changes to my css file which was linked up before I made any files but now I want to link it up the link needs to go backwards out of the file to the homepage file and then into the css file. What do I type in order to send something to my css from my js file?

Comment: Your javascript runs client side... it has no access to change your css file, but you could use the root like so: /css/mycssfile.css

Comment: the above was a made up scenario in order to make my question simple to follow. i am not actually doing anything with css or js i just thought it would be easier to follow i actually using the require in php to connect to a different php file. But really observant thanks :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do some research into relative URLs. It's likely that all you need is something like:

```
../css/mycssfile.css
```

to access it from your JS file. The double-dots mean "go up one level".

Comment: thanks for the title change i had no clue what to call this :) & thanks for the answer, i had seen this before when trying to find it out by linking on dreamweaver but had no clue as to what it meant. This will help me tidy up my very messy website which currently sits in one very messed up unordered file. **I now realise i had been forgetting to put the / in it thanks.**